# ggplot: extract selected subplots from faceted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I have the following data and a faceted plot generated from it.

```
# Data generation
dataPlot <- mtcars %>% select(mpg, wt, carb) %>% 
  group_by(carb) %>% mutate(N = n()) %>% data.frame()

# Original Faceted plot
g1 <- ggplot(dataPlot, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~carb) + ggtitle("Original plot")
```

I would like to extract the following plot from the above plot. For comparison, I am generating it from the data itself.

```
# Refined plot with minimum 4 points
g2 <- ggplot(dataPlot %>% filter(N > 3), aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~carb) + ggtitle("Refined plot")

# Plots together
grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

How to extract the plot `g2` from the plot `g1` using only the content in `g1`, instead of generating it again from data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `str(g1)`, it a a list with a bunch of information about what to plot. The first element is `data`, which you can override, effectively changing `g1` into `g2`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

g1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_wrap(~ carb) + 
    ggtitle("Original plot")


g1$data <- g1$data %>% group_by(carb) %>% filter(n() > 3)

g1
```

[image]

That said, replotting is usually simpler than messing with ggplot object internals directly.