# Creating an inset of a line graph on R studio (ggplot, facet_wrap)

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have created a facet_wrap plot to show the sea surface temperatures of four different regions of the Great Barrier Reef, from 1985 to 2017. I would like to create insets/focused images/rectangles for certain year periods (e.g. 1997-98, 2015-16). What would be the best function to do this? My code is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

FN <- read_csv("FINALSST.csv")

FN2 <- mutate(FN, Time2=as.Date(Time, format="%d/%m/%Y"))

FN2$Region <- factor(FN2$Region, levels=c("Far Northern", "Northern", "Central", "Southern"))

ggplot(data = FN2, aes(Time2, Value, col=Variable)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.1) +
  geom_point(size = 0.1) + 
  labs(title = "Great Barrier Reef SSTs from 1985 to 2017", y = "Sea Surface Temperature (°C)", x = "Date") + 
  facet_wrap(~Region, ncol=1)
```

I have also attached the image of the current plot:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/reference/inset_element.html) for your insets?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Produce an inset in each facet of an R ggplot while preserving colours of the original facet content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579733/produce-an-inset-in-each-facet-of-an-r-ggplot-while-preserving-colours-of-the-or)